# SQLite3: IF row exist then incriment value ELSE insert new row

Tags: sqlite

Good afternoon. I try to execute such scenario with one request: I have a table in which every hour the value is entered. I would like to insert a new entry if the date of the last bet has passed more than 1 hour, and if within an hour, then increment the value

**Example:**

```
+------------+-------------------+
| value      | date              |
+------------+-------------------+
|     100    |2020-08-06 12:12:12|
+------------+-------------------+
|     100    |2020-08-06 **11:11:00**|
+---------------------------------
```

New notification

```
+------------+-------------------+
|     50     |2020-08-06 **11:20:00**|
+------------+-------------------+
```

=>

```
+------------+-------------------+
| value      | date              |
+------------+-------------------+
|     100    |2020-08-06 12:12:12|
+------------+-------------------+
|     150    |2020-08-06 **11:11:00**|
+---------------------------------
```

NEED:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM energy_consumption WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now') AND DATETIME('now'))
    UPDATE energy_consumption SET consumption_tarif_1 = consumption_tarif_1 + 100 WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now') AND DATETIME('now')
ELSE
    INSERT INTO energy_consumption (counter_type_id, consumption_tarif_1, consumption_tarif_2, consumption_tarif_3) VALUES(1, 100, 100, 100)
```

BUT `IF - ELSE` - don't support on SQLite 3.x

I'm trying to do something like an electricity meter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 statements:

```
UPDATE energy_consumption 
SET consumption_tarif_1 = consumption_tarif_1 + 100 
WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now') AND DATETIME('now')
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM energy_consumption 
  WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now') AND DATETIME('now')
);

INSERT INTO energy_consumption (counter_type_id, consumption_tarif_1, consumption_tarif_2, consumption_tarif_3) 
SELECT 1, 100, 100, 100
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM energy_consumption 
  WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now') AND DATETIME('now')
);
```

Only 1 of them will be executed since both contain mutually exclusive conditions with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: It's a pretty good solution. thank you. I, too, in this moment tried to something do. Now I sit I test for different cases. ```INSERT INTO energy_consumption (date, counter_type_id, consumption_tarif_1) VALUES(( SELECT date FROM energy_consumption WHERE date like strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00', 'now')),1, 23) ON CONFLICT(date) DO UPDATE SET counter_type_id=1, consumption_tarif_1 = consumption_tarif_1 + 50 ;```

Comment: Your solution seems to me more flexible

Comment: ON CONFLICT works if there is a unique constraint violation.